# Make an API call on the front end using next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma

New to next.js and trying to hook up making Prisma calls from my components.
Following the docs and examples by doing this:

```
try {
  await fetch('/api/postQuestion', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```

however, it does nothing at all.

Here is postQuestion.js:

```
import prisma from "../../lib/prisma.js";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        return await createQuestion(req, res);
    }
    else {
        return res.status(405).json({ message: 'Method not allowed', success: false });
    }
}

async function createQuestion(req, res) {
    try {
        const newQuestion = await prisma.question.create({
            data: {
                question: 'wow?',
                option1: 'blue',
                option2: 'red'
            }
        });
        return res.status(200).json(newQuestion, {success: true});
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Request error", error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Error creating question", success:false });
    }
}
```

Comment: _"it does nothing at all"_ - can you clarify what you mean by that? What were you expecting your request to do? You're not handling the response you get from the request.

Answer (score -2):

The proper way to fetch local API data is using getStaticProps functions and return the data

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  // Call an external API endpoint to get posts.
  // You can use any data fetching library
  const res = await fetch('https://.../posts')
  const posts = await res.json()

  // By returning { props: { posts } }, the Blog component
  // will receive `posts` as a prop at build time
  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: This would be for non-static content though, like a user creating something via POST. So I wouldn't use getStaticProps right?